# How to find all the roots of $xe^{-x}=A$

Tags: calculus, lambert-w

I am trying to find all the roots of the equation $xe^{-x}=A$.

I tried using LambdertW function. I used
$-xe^{-x}=-A$

Solution is $x = -LW(-A)$, where $LW$ is the Lambertw finction.

As $-xe^{-x}$ is negative, decreases intially and then increases close to zero, there will two roots corresponding to -A.

When I use the lambertW function in matlab, I am only able to get one root out of the two roots.

Is there any way to get both the roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/lambertw.html, the syntax for both roots should be `lambertw(0,k)` and `lambertw(-1,k)`, as the description says:

> `lambertw(k,x)` is the kth branch of the Lambert W function. This syntax returns real values only if k = 0 or k = -1.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

You look for the zero(s) of
$$f(x)=x\,e^{-x}-A$$ Its derivative cancels for $x=1$ and the second derivative test shows this is a maximum. So,

- if $A > \frac 1e$, no solution
- if $A =\frac 1e$, one double root
- if 0 < $A < \frac 1e$, two solutions $x_1=-W_0(-A)$ and  $x_2=-W_{-1}(-A)$
- if $A=0$, the trivial solution
- if $A<0$, one solution $x=-W_0(-A)$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @sar1729. You are very welcome !